# Satapatha Brahmana 10:4:2:23

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, shatapatha-brahmana

Wikipedia mentions that Rik-Veda has 432 000 syllables and refers to Satapatha Brahmana as the source of this information.
Satapatha Brahmana 10:4:2:23 states the following:

"He arranged the Rik-verses into twelve thousand of Brihatîs, for of that extent are the verses created by Prajapati. At the thirtieth arrangement they came to an end in the Paṅktis; and because it was at the thirtieth arrangement that they came to an end, there are thirty nights in the month; and because it was in the Paṅktis, therefore Prajapati is 'pankta' (fivefold). There are one hundred-and-eight hundred Paṅktis."

12000 (Brihatis) x 36 (syllables) = 432000

10800 (Panktis) x 40 (syllables) = 432000

My questions: Does Rik-Veda consist of Brihati meters with 36 syllables, or of Pankti meters with 40 syllables?

If it consists of both, then the total amount of syllables would be 864000.

According to my understanding Rik-Veda has many different meters, like Trishtubh, Gayatri, Jagati etc.

Who can explain to me the Satapatha Brahmana text?

What is the meaning of the thirtieth arrangement where the Brihatis came to an end in the Panktis?

(I am writing Rik with ka instead of ga, because my Guru'ji says ka is more original, only later it developed into ga. R stands for infinite dynamism of the absolute Being and ka stands for its point value.)

Comment: You are correct Rig-veda has many meters like Trishtubh, Gyatri, Jagati, Anushtup etc. For e.g. The opening verse of Rigveda Agnimile Purohitam is written in Gyatri chhanda.